# delegate on a child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Suppose I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="remove">remove</span>
</div>
```

and jquery:

```
$(".container").delegate(".remove", "click", function() {           
    alert('yes');       
});
```

This works, but now I have HTML like:

```
<div class"container">
  <div>
     <span class="remove">remove</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

or even

```
<div class"container">
  <div>
     <div>
        <span class="remove">remove</span>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So how can I make the jquery work in this case, so that if finds the .remove element in a hierarchy of elements and make the click event work?

NOTE: I'm adding the elements dynamically (using clone function)!

Comment: Is there some reason you think it won't work? Did you try it?

Comment: i tried it and it doesn't work, but I forget to mention that I add elements dynamically with clone, maybe that's a different

Comment: @Lud: I guess the `class"container"` over `class="container"` is a typo when posting the question, rather than your actual code?

Comment: @Lud: You can see your existing code works in this JSFiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/d3xf5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This will still work](http://jsfiddle.net/d3xf5/). As long as the element you're delegating the event to is an ancestor of the element, the element will receive the event.

An exception to this is where an element which is a more direct ancestor stops the propagation of the event using [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/), or by returning `false` in it's handler;

```
$(".container").delegate(".remove", "click", function() {           
    // This will never get executed, as the first handler cancels the propagation.
    alert('yes');       
});

$(".container > div").delegate(".remove", "click", function(e) {           
    // This handler get the event first as it is closer to the source of the event.
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**FYI**, if you're using jQuery > 1.7, you should consider using the new [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method as `on()` was implemented to disperse the confusion over [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live), [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) and [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind). It is expected that these older methods will be depreciated in 1.8. The following is equivilent for what you're currently using;

```
$(".container").on("click", ".remove", function(e) {           
    alert('yes');
});
```

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't seem to work in my case - I'm adding these elements dynamically using the clone function, could that be the reason?

Comment: @Lud: As long as you're not adding the `.container` element dynamically, you're fine. If you're adding the `.container` element dynamically, you'll need to either rebind the event handler every time, or better yet, delegate the event handler to a element higher up the ancestor chain which is always in the DOM.

Comment: @Lud: To be absolutely sure the element you're attaching the handler to exists, you could do `$(document).delegate('.container .remove', 'click', function () { alert('yes'); });`

Comment: If i do that, then the alert is triggered! But it seems that I try to get the object with $(this) (in the event handler), it's not the span element with class 'remove'?

Comment: @Lud: Should be; http://jsfiddle.net/d3xf5/1/. Can you post an updated Fiddle or update your question?

Comment: @Lud: If it works by delegating to `document` but not to `.container`, it means that the `.container` does not have the event handler bound to it; either because it's being replaced in the DOM, or you're attaching the handler via `delegate()` outside a `$(document).ready()` block (i.e. before it's available).